# Adding variation types and sub variation types

Tags: nodes, commerce

I'm new to *commerce kickstart* and am wondering how I can create variation types and "sub" variation types? I would like to create an architecture that allows me to have a variation type `fruits` and then sub types `apples` and `oranges` e.g. - how can I do this?

Comment: You can create `fruits` as taxonomy.

Comment: Where do I do this? I can't find a `taxonomy` edit point in the menu

Comment: `Taxonomy` be added to product type. If you want to use `taxonomy` as menu, then you can use `taxonomy menu` module.https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu

Comment: @JayendraKainthola why isn't it an answer?

Comment: @Mołot, I was busy in other stuff, so I added comment that OP can follow the same. Thanks for your suggestion, I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `fruits` as taxonomy and assign this to your product type.

Creating Taxonomy:

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Taxonomy.
- Click on "Add vocabulary" link to create new taxonomy and it will redirect you to taxonomy form.
- Add `name(fruits)` for `vocabulary` and save the form and it will redirect you to list of `taxonomy`.
- Click on `list terms` in row of `fruits` taxonomy.
- Click on 'Add Term' link to add new term for `fruits` taxonomy.

Assign `Taxonomy` to product type:

- Go to Administration -> Store -> Product
- Click on `Product types` link in top of page and it will redirect you to list of `Product types`.
- Click on `Manage fields` link in row of `Product`.
- Add `Term Reference` field and select `fruits` as vocabulary and save the form.

Selecting taxonomy as menu:

If you want to display taxonomy as menu, you can use '[Taxonomy menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)' module.

> Transform any of your taxonomy vocabularies into existing menus
>   easily!

`Taxonomy menu` will create your `Taxonomy Term` as menu item.

Configuration of Menu:

- Edit your taxonomy in admin and select Menu location for `taxonomy menu`.

Comment: Well, thank you for that, but these instructions don;'t exactly martch my commerce kickstart interface and I actually wasn't able to create sub categories... :( However, i appreciate the attempt. I got stuck when creating the menu but I installed and enabled `Taxonomy menu` but there's no `Taxonomy Term` menu item anywhere...

Comment: @cerr, Have you created `Taxonomy Term` for the `Taxonomy`.